# How can you integrate SharePoint 2019 with Hadoop distributed file system

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-integration

How can you integrate SharePoint 2019 with Hadoop distributed file system. We are storing and managing bulk data( about    >10 000 items )on the document library and  there are issues handling this large documents especially on retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

There wouldn't be any integration point. You may be able to find a 3rd party solution (i.e. AvePoint used to offer one) that allows you to view content on a file share, but if you want the SharePoint features of version control, metadata, and so forth it needs to reside in SharePoint.

In general you shouldn't be having any issues with that number of documents even in a single library. You may need to configure index, filters, and views on the library but that isn't much content.

[Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-B8588DAE-9387-48C2-9248-C24122F07C59)

Comment: we are not  decommissiong Sharepoint , the users will still manage and store documents there but we have issues with Search service application(separate site) and database query.

Comment: You should create a new post to t-shoot your search issues. 10K documents is very small (for reference, my farm has 2+ million documents and that is also considered small).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to improve performance on that document library:

1. Create indices on the columns used most for filtering.
2. Move the site collection that contains the document library into its own content database.
3. Implement Remote Blob storage for your SQL instance (in my experience that helps mostly if you have very large files in your library).

Besides, 10K items is not massive amount. Most probably something is wrongly set up with your SQL instance. 
Look at this series (there are 3 videos) It is talking about SP2013 but all recommendations will largely apply to SP2019:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Tuning-SQL-Server-2012-for-SharePoint-2013/Tuning-SQL-Server-2012-for-SharePoint-2013-01-Key-SQL-Server-and-SharePoint-Server-Integration-Conce